# Replacing repeated elements in array

Tags: linux, bash

I am new in bash scripting and I need help in my task...
I have an array :

```
arr=( one two tree four five six seven one  four  nine one  two  one  ten )
```

I need to change it on the rule : If element repeated first time add 1 to the end, if twice - 2.

Expecting result:

```
arr=( one two tree four five six seven one1 four1 nine one2 two1 one3 ten )
```

My code :

```
for i in ${!arr[*]}
do
    k=1
    for j in ${!arr[*]}
        do
        if [[ ( ${arr[$i]} = ${arr[$j]} ) && ( $i > $j )  ]] ;then
            arr[$i]=$(echo ${arr[$j]}$k)
            ((j++))
            ((k++))
        fi
    done
    echo ${arr[$i]}
    ((i++))
done
```

Please, give me advice how to resolve this task...

Answer (score 2):

Use an associative array to hold the current count for each word.

```
declare -A count
for i in ${!arr[*]}
do
    if [[ -n "${count[${arr[$i]}]}" ]]
    then 
        ((count[${arr[$i]}]++))
        arr[$i]=${arr[$i]}${count[${arr[$i]}]}
    else
        count[${arr[$i]}]=0
    fi
done
```

Comment: all count will be 1 in your solution

Comment: Why? `((count[$arr[$i]]++))` increments the count each time it's used.

Comment: when I make echo ${count[*]} it holds only 1 1 1 .....

Comment: I fixed the problems.

Comment: A shorter version: `for i in ${!arr[*]}; do ((count[${arr[$i]}]++)) && arr[$i]+=$((count[${arr[$i]}]-1)); done`

Comment: @KamilCuk shorter != better

Comment: @Barmar Please can you explain one more thing. What should I do if I expect next result:
arr=( one0 two1 three four3 five six seven one7 four8 nine one10 two11 one12 ten )
where number index of repeated element

Comment: That's very different. You have to go through the array twice. The first pass discovers all the repeated elements, the second pass adds the index to them.